# getting full number of comments of facebook status in API v2.6

Tags: facebook, comments

How to get number of all comments (number of status comment + number of comments of comments) without looping over every comment?

This parameters show only number of direct comments of status, without nested comments

> ?fields=comments.summary(true).limit(0)

How to do it similarly to FQL? 
FQL requests have no problem with it

> SELECT id,likes,post_fbid,time,fromid,text,text_tags,parent_id FROM
>   comment WHERE post_id = %post_id%

it returns all comments (nested or not) as is. easy to count and easy to check of something changed

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer: you should use filter = stream
likes this

> ?fields=comments.summary(true).filter(stream).limit(0)

It's in the official documentation, but was not very obvious to me, that it can be used in object endpoint and not only in object/comments.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/object/comments#readmodifiers